# TIC TAC TOE in Swift 3 win and draw issue

Tags: swift

I got the win part working but i don't understand why when the game is over it doesn't display the massage " its a draw"... i need correction in my code. i've tried but i'm a begginer in game coding. i would appreciate the help very much.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var winnerLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var playAgainButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func playAgain(_ sender: Any) {
         activePlayer = 2
         activeGame = true
         gameState = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

         for i in 1..<10{
            if let button = view.viewWithTag(i) as? UIButton {
                button.setImage(nil, for: [])
            }

            winnerLabel.isHidden = true
            playAgainButton.isHidden = true
        }
    }

    // 1 is nought, 2 is cross
    var activePlayer = 2
    var activeGame = true
    var gameState = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] // 0 - empty 1 - cross 2 - nought

    let winningCombinations = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6]]

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {  // all of the buttons are in this same IBAction.
        let activePosition = sender.tag - 1

        if gameState[activePosition] == 0  && activeGame{
            gameState[activePosition] = activePlayer    // helps type just one answer. either nought or cross.

            if activePlayer == 2 {
                sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "cross.png"), for: []) // makes it show the nought.png when button is pressed
                activePlayer = 1
            }else{
                sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "nought.png"), for: []) // makes it show the cross.png when button is pressed
                activePlayer = 2
            }

            for combinations in winningCombinations{
                if gameState[combinations[0]] != 0 && gameState[combinations[0]] == gameState[combinations[1]] && gameState[combinations[1]] == gameState[combinations[2]]{
                    // we have a winner!
                    activeGame = false

                    winnerLabel.isHidden = false
                    playAgainButton.isHidden = false

                    if gameState[combinations[0]] == 1 {
                        winnerLabel.text = "0 WINS!"
                    }else if gameState[combinations[1]] == 2{
                        winnerLabel.text = "X WINS!"
                    }else{
                        winnerLabel.text = "IT'S A DRAW!"  // THE PROBLEM. IT DOESN'T DISPLAY THE TEXT "ITS A DRAW" HOW CAN I FIX IT? ANY HELP WILL BE APPRECIATED! THANK YOU !!!!
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Because your `else` for the draw scenario is inside your `if` that has determined you have a winner.  If you have a draw then you don't have a winner, so the else is never reached.  The draw state is determined by not having a winner after 9 turns.

Comment: i understand what you are saying but, you think you can show it in actual code ? like i have ideas to make it but everything i think i can come up with fails.. now i don't understand much coding yet im still a beginner. so if its not  too much to ask that would help me a ton ! thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic for determining a draw is incorrect.  A draw occurs when 9 moves have been made and there is no winner.  Your code checks for a draw inside the "we have a winner" block; you can only reach it if the check for a winning combination has returned true.  If it has then you can't possibly have a draw, since you have already determined that you have a winner.

You need to add a turn counter, and if the turn counter reaches 9 without there being a winner then you have a draw.

```
var turnCount = 0

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {  // all of the buttons are in this same IBAction.
    let activePosition = sender.tag - 1

    turnCount+= 1

    if gameState[activePosition] == 0  && activeGame{
        gameState[activePosition] = activePlayer    // helps type just one answer. either nought or cross.

        if activePlayer == 2 {
            sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "cross.png"), for: []) // makes it show the nought.png when button is pressed
            activePlayer = 1
        } else {
            sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "nought.png"), for: []) // makes it show the cross.png when button is pressed
            activePlayer = 2
        }

        for combinations in winningCombinations {
            if gameState[combinations[0]] != 0 && gameState[combinations[0]] == gameState[combinations[1]] && gameState[combinations[1]] == gameState[combinations[2]]{
                // we have a winner!
                activeGame = false

                winnerLabel.isHidden = false
                playAgainButton.isHidden = false

                if gameState[combinations[0]] == 1 {
                    winnerLabel.text = "0 WINS!"
                } else if gameState[combinations[1]] == 2{
                    winnerLabel.text = "X WINS!"
                }
            }
        }

        if activeGame && turnCount == 9 {
            winnerLabel.text = "IT'S A DRAW!"
            activeGame = false
        }
    }
}
```